# Share and persist knowledge while using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

What will encourage developers working on application maintenance and development using Eclipse to contribute knowledge gained on application, while fixing an issue or carrying out new development. For example Some test data/scenario which is relevant to a java file or some very potent information about the program. This knowledge can be persisted in some way, but the key here is would any developer like to share the knowledge imbibed while working on solving issues or creating new files beyond adding comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and add a wiki editor within the developpers's eclipse.
See [**EclipseWiki**](http://eclipsewiki.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

Or you can add a special brand of wiki, like the [**FitNesse**](http://fitnesse.org/) one (see its [one minute description](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.OneMinuteDescription)).
See **[BrandXI](http://www.bandxi.com/fitnesse/features-0.html)**

[alt text http://www.bandxi.com/fitnesse/images/features-new-wizard1.gif](http://www.bandxi.com/fitnesse/images/features-new-wizard1.gif)

It will capture what the software should do and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191482/share-and-persist-knowledge-while-using-eclipse/2191523#2191523) to use a project wiki stored as plain text files in the Eclipse project. I find that to be a very useful way of writing documentation. However, I would suggest using [Mylyn WikiText](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/WikiText), which is already installed if you have an Eclipse 3.5 with Mylyn. If not, it can be installed via the Galileo update site. It offers a [great editor](http://greensopinion.blogspot.com/2009/03/mylyn-wikitext-10-released.html), exports to various formats (HTML, PDF, etc.) and supports many different wiki markup flavours (Textile, Confluence, MediaWiki, and Trac).

Comment: I left out Mylyn! Good catch. +1